# Group results with max elements per group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to divide records into groups that have max n elements per group id, I need extra column to be some kind of counter that will increment by one when it reaches certain number of rows.
I'm not speaking English native so I've build example code to show what data I have and what results I need.

Here is sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c9cf5/1

and here is sqlfiddle code:

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 
    (
     id int
    );

INSERT INTO tab1 (id) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO tab1 (id) VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO tab1 (id) VALUES (3)
INSERT INTO tab1 (id) VALUES (4)
INSERT INTO tab1 (id) VALUES (5)
INSERT INTO tab1 (id) VALUES (6)
INSERT INTO tab1 (id) VALUES (7)
INSERT INTO tab1 (id) VALUES (8)
INSERT INTO tab1 (id) VALUES (9)
INSERT INTO tab1 (id) VALUES (10)
INSERT INTO tab1 (id) VALUES (11)
INSERT INTO tab1 (id) VALUES (12)
INSERT INTO tab1 (id) VALUES (13)
INSERT INTO tab1 (id) VALUES (14)
INSERT INTO tab1 (id) VALUES (15)
INSERT INTO tab1 (id) VALUES (16)
INSERT INTO tab1 (id) VALUES (17)
INSERT INTO tab1 (id) VALUES (18)
INSERT INTO tab1 (id) VALUES (18)
INSERT INTO tab1 (id) VALUES (20)

SELECT id,
NTILE(4) OVER(ORDER BY id DESC) AS X
from tab1
```

My table with data looks like this:

```
 id
 --
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
10
```

and I need result that look looks like this:

```
 id | group
 --
 1 | 1
 2 | 1
 3 | 1
 4 | 1
 5 | 2
 6 | 2
 7 | 2
 8 | 2
 9 | 3
10 | 3
```

In above example I want to group all records into groups containing max 4 elements, so records 1-4 are in group 1, records 5-8 in group 2 and record 9-10 are in third.

Probably there is build in function that can do this, but because of my English skills I wasn't able to find it.

I've tried counting all elements in table and dividing it by number or elements and then using it in NTILE, but this way I get equal group and that's not result I need.

Comment: it can be achieved through NTILE then what is your main problem lies ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT  id,
        group_id = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) - 1) / 4 + 1
FROM    my_table
```

This will work even if there are gaps in your `id`, like 1,2,5,10.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `row_number() over (order by id)`, you can just divide the row number for example with 4, then you'll get the number to increase every 4 rows.

SQL Fiddle seems to be broken, so I can't edit your example.

Comment: Are you sure windowed row_number is in 2005?

Comment: Row number exists in 2005, but the latest changes like lag() are missing

Comment: I mean ORDER BY in OVER clause?

Comment: @lad2025 yes it exists in 2005

Comment: @Misiu OK, thanks for clarification, in MSDN it starts with 2008

Comment: @lad2025 I see it starting in 2005: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms186734(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: @ZoffDino Great, thanks for link, my search engine always sends me to 2008 :)